# Get phone screen size using windowmanager

Tags: java, android

I my android app, i change the wallpaer/desktop image. How do i get the size of screen of the phone?

Note :I donot need the size of current activity but the screen.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

int width = display.getWidth()
int height = display.getHeight()
```

Does the above code return the size of screen or current activity?Also  display.getHeight() and display.getWidth methods are depreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height/4744499#4744499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
int screenHeight = (short) Activity.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
int screenWidth  = (short) Activity.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

source:
[Android | Getting screen height as width and screen width as height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999427/android-getting-screen-height-as-width-and-screen-width-as-height)

Or to sum up @Parag Chauhan,

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

source:[Get Screen width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height/4744499#4744499)